# Array not containing both values from query

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am trying to get an array to contain two values; SkillID and Description. However when I print the value of the array it is only showing Description. How can I get an array to show both??

```
$skillresult = $con->query("SELECT userskills.`SkillID`, `Description`, `Experience` FROM `User` INNER JOIN `userskills` ON User.`UserId` = userskills.`UserId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `Skills` ON userskills.`SkillID` = Skills.`SkillID` WHERE user.`UserID` ='$User'") 
    or die(mysqli_error($con));

    $skills_array = array();

    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($skillresult))
    {
    if (!isset($skills_array[$r['SkillID']]))
    {
        $skills_array[$r['SkillID']] = array();
    }
    $skills_array[$r['SkillID']][] = $r['Description'];
}
```

Print Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Java ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Unix ) )
```

Description 'Java' should have the SkillID of '1' and Unix '6'.

Comment: You are storing an array per skillid, is that intended or are you going for a 1 to 1. $skills_array[$r['SkillID']] = $r['Description']; if you arent getting the right numbers that join might be off.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am intending to have an array per skillid. Which join, the left outer join or the inner join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `$skills_array` array really supposed to be 2-dimensional?
Isn't this what you really want?

```
Array ( 1 => Java, 6 => Unix)
```

In which case, this could work:

```
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($skillresult))
{
    $skills_array[$r['SkillID']] = $r['Description'];
}
```

Comment: None of these suggested changes changed the contents of the printed array. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I am fetching my results using : `print_r(array_values($skills_array));`. Do you think this is incorrect?

Comment: Aah I see, that could be the culprit, according to documentation `array_values() returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically. `

Comment: Using `print_r($r)` I get: `Array ( [SkillID] => 1 [Description] => Java [Experience] => 3 ) Array ( [SkillID] => 5 [Description] => Linux [Experience] => 6 )
`. Which is correct.

Comment: Well according to what you've said in your previous comment, the problem is `array_values()`. If you simply use `print_r($skills_array)` then you'll see that your code works as expected.

Comment: Using `print_r($skills_array)` I get: Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => Java ) [5] => Array ( [0] => Linux ) ). Which contains the correct number and description, but not in the correct position I'd like: Array ( [1] => Java, [5] => Linux )

Comment: But that's exactly what I've suggested in my answer.